# Borrar elementos repetidos de una lista

Tags: java

Estoy intentando realizar un ejercicio pero realmente nose como hacer el ejercicio usando la clase que me están dando, ya que el problema que tengo es con el uso de IndexedList. si alguien me pudiera dar algún consejo/pista o algún ejemplo sería de gran ayuda.

```
 public static <E> IndexedList<E> deleteRepeated(IndexedList<E> l) {

 }// de indexedList
```

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es crear un nuevo IndexedList e iterar sobre el original para comprobar si cada elemento existe en el nuevo IndexedList y de lo contrario agregarlo. Esto te puede servir https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.net4j.util.doc%2Fjavadoc%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fnet4j%2Futil%2Fcollection%2FIndexedList.html

Answer (score 2):

No conozco la clase IndexedList, pero te dejo un ejemplo de lo que puedes hacer con Java8

```
//creamos la lista inicial
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add("cadena1");
lista.add("cadena2");
lista.add("cadena1");
lista.add("cadena3");
lista.add("cadena1");
//en este punto nuestra lista tiene los siguientes elementos [cadena1,cadena2,cadena1,cadena3,cadena1 ]

//la magia comienza aca
//pasamos la lista a un stream ya que nos ofrece el metodo distinct el cual elimina los duplicados y retorna un stream
//luego agrupamos el stream y lo volcamos en una lista nuevamente.
lista = lista.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

//imprimimos la lista utilizando la referencia al metodo println
lista.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Saludos